# DELETE REQUEST (MongoDB, express, handlebars)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, http-delete, express-handlebars

I am having trouble making a delete request in my application. I have a database of reviews, which I alter with my application.

I am trying to make a function that will delete a document from my database and redirect the user to another page.

Here is my handelbars view(i am trying to set it up so if a user clicks on the link, it will excecute the delete method):

```
<h1>{{rev.title}}</h1>
<h2>{{rev.snippet}}</h2>
<p>{{rev.body}}</p>

<a class ="rem" data-method="delete" href="/reviews/{{this.id}}" >Delete</a>
 //some javascript??!!
```

This is my router in the routers file:

```
router.delete('/:id',reviewController.review_delete);
```

This is my method in the controller file:

```
const review_delete =  (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params._id;
    mySchemas.reviews.findByIdAndRemove(id, function (err){
        if(err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.redirect("./reviews");
        }
    });

}
```

I've tried multiple things, but i do not yet understand how to actually make it so that the user can delete things.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this

```
 <a class ="rem" data-method="delete" href="/reviews/{{this.id}}" >Delete</a>
```

Do this

```
<a class ="rem" href="/reviews/{{this.id}}" onclick="delete({{this.id}})" >Delete</a>
```

```
 function delete(id) {
   const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     // some code
   };
   xhttp.open("DELETE", `<your-server-host>/reviews/${id}`, true);
   xhttp.send();
 
  }
```

Comment: Hmm, it didnt work. The url id from request to the server had an undefined value, when i loged it to the console.

Comment: by using req.params.id you are getting undefined in the server side ?

Comment: try passing id to an id attribute of anchor element and from document.getElementById and get the id attribute